# How to convert json object to mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, deserialization

I new to javascript. How to convert json object to mongoose model and result should be like collection in c#.

Below is my code snippet

```
var dbConnection = mongoose.connect('mongodb://example-server/db', {},     function (err) 
{
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error occurred' + err);
        }
});

    mongoose.model('customer', customerSchema);
    mongoose.model('customer').find({ 'Name': 'XXX' }, function (err, articles) {
        var json= JSON.stringify(customer, null, 2);
        console.log("stringify Log: " + json);
    });
```

Output - Json object

In .net we use below code to deserialize json object to an collection and then we can use the list to search for data or insert data.

List lstCustomerREO = JsonHelper.Deserialize>(_response.Content);

I need similar scenario in javascript.

Comment: C# code - List<CustomerREO> lstCustomerREO = JsonHelper.Deserialize<List<CustomerREO>>(_response.Content);

Comment: `articles` in callback is already a `list` that you are expecting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongoose does this automatically for you. The `articles` parameter in the callback for the find method will contain an array of customers matching your query try the following updated code:

```
mongoose.model('customer', customerSchema);
mongoose.model('customer').find({ 'Name': 'XXX' }, function (err, articles) 
{
    var json = JSON.stringify(articles);
    console.log("stringify Log: " + json);
});
```

Comment: Thanks.If my output has 2 json objects, then how do i just view first or last. json[0] or json[1] does not work. I also need to view the property value for a particular object. like json[0].name or json[0].age does not work either.

Comment: well you are stringifying the json variable so it is a string and no longer an object. if you want just the first item in the array then use articles[0] so the code looks like this. var json = JSON.stringify(articles[0]);